# How to modify some but not all variables of a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose there is a data.frame where some variables are coded as integers:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- as.integer(c(2,3,4,5,6))
c <- as.integer(c(5,1,0,9,2))
d <- as.integer(c(5,6,7,3,1))
e <- c(2,6,1,2,3)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
str(df)
```

Suppose I want to convert columns b to d to numeric:

```
varlist <- names(df)[2:4]

lapply(varlist, function(x) {
df$x <- as.numeric(x, data=x)
    })

str(df)
```

does not work.

I tried:

```
df$b <- as.numeric(b, data=df)
df$c <- as.numeric(c, data=df)
df$d <- as.numeric(d, data=df)
str(df)
```

which works fine.

Questions:
How do I do this (in a loop or better with `lapply`, [but I'm a Stata person and as such used to writing loops])?
And more generally: how do I apply any function to a list of variables in a data.frame
(e.g. multiply each variable on the list with some other variable[which is always stays the same,
      BONUS: or changes with each variable on the list])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question you can use `sapply`:

```
df[2:4] <- sapply(df[2:4],as.numeric)
```

for the second you should use `mapply`. For example to multiply the 3 variables(2 to 4) by some 3 different random scalars:

```
df[2:4] <-  mapply(function(x,y)df[[x]]*y,2:4,rnorm(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[,2:4] <- sapply(df[,2:4], as.numeric)
```

As for your second question, if you want to say multiply column c by 5

```
df$c <- df$c * 5
```

Or any vector the same length as c, maybe a new column multiplying c by d

```
df$cd <- df$c * df$d
```

Comment: thanks, too. But agstudy gave the second answer in an `apply` format too.